# Touchpad does not work after upgrade to disco dingo (19.04) - Solution

Tags: mouse, touchpad, 19.04

Solution:

Thanks to miezbla and [this solution](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1803600), I was able to solve this issue permanently. Following I will conclude this solution for everyone who has the same issue:

1. You can fix this issue temporarily with `dmesg | grep -i elantech`
2. You can fix this issue permanently by adding this boot parameter`psmouse.elantech_smbus=0` to the kernel.

   2.1 - open the terminal ant type in the command `sudo nano /etc/default/grub` (if you prefer a GUI-editor, replace nano with gedit or your favorite editor)

   2.2 - add psmouse.elantech_smbus=0 to the file, save and close the editor

   2.3 - run `sudo update-grub` to update GRUB's configuration file

Hope this helps.

original question:

I've installed Ubuntu 19.04 on my Thinkpad L480. But I can't use my touchpad or pointng stick.
Ubuntu does not detect the touchpad:

```
user@ThinkPad-L480:~$ xinput list
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Dell Dell USB Optical Mouse               id=9    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Sleep Button                              id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=10   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ ThinkPad Extra Buttons
```

I already tried to reset BIOS and reinstall ubuntu. I run Windows10 (shame on me) from the same SSD and the touchpad works fine. Touchpad also works on Ubuntu 18.04 and 18.10 live-image and on installed Ubuntu 18.10.

Does anyone know, what to do?

Maybe this output is useful too:

```
user@ThinkPad-L480:~$ dpkg -l | egrep 'libinput|Synaptics'
ii  libinput-bin                               1.12.6-1                             amd64        input device management and event handling library - udev quirks
ii  libinput10:amd64                           1.12.6-1                             amd64        input device management and event handling library - shared library
ii  xserver-xorg-input-libinput                0.28.2-2                             amd64        X.Org X server -- libinput input driver
ii  xserver-xorg-input-synaptics               1.9.1-1ubuntu1                       amd64        Synaptics TouchPad driver for X.Org server
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've had the same issue after upgrading my Ubuntu Budgie from 18.10 to 19.04 (with the same Lenovo model). Strange, that it worked before. With a live session of Budgie 19.04 it's also not working.

For me, the solution offered in [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1091635/elantech-touchpad-not-working-after-upgrading-to-18-10-from-18-04-thinkpad-l4) thread worked perfectly. Just add `psmouse.elantech_smbus=0` to your boot options, update grub and restart.

Comment: `sudo nano /etc/default/grub` set  `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="psmouse.elantech_smbus=0"` `sudo update-grub` and reboot

Answer (score 1):

Ubuntu 19.04 comes with fwupd service. Try to use it to find if there are any updates available for your firmware.

```
sudo fwupdmgr refresh
sudo fwupdmgr update
```

Also make sure that you have Synaptics TouchPad driver if you're using Xorg:

```
sudo apt install xserver-xorg-input-synaptics
```

Lastly open applications menu and go to Updates -> Settings, then switch to Additional Drivers. You can also open it from terminal:

```
/usr/bin/python3 /usr/bin/software-properties-gtk --open-tab 4
```

Maybe there are additional drivers available for your hardware.

Comment: If I try to update my firmware I get this message:

`user@ThinkPad-L480:~$ sudo fwupdmgr update
cannot handle firmware requirement 'firmware'`

Comment: you can try snap version of fwupdmgr, `sudo apt-get remove fwupdmgr && sudo snap install fwupdmgr`

Comment: I'm `E: Unable to locate package fwupdmgr`

Comment: and `$ sudo snap install fwupdmgr
error: snap "fwupdmgr" not found`

Comment: my mistake, the snap name is `fwupd`, but there is security issue with it, so first try `sudo install fwupd` and read about it, then if you want to try it still, then use `snap install fwupd --classic`, but I recommend you to remove this snap as soon you finish working with it

Comment: Thank you! Seems there are no releases for my device...
I still don't get, whats 'wrong' with my touchpad... :/

Comment: this is not working! installing but touchpad still not working